# Intel XDK "Push to Testing Server" not pushing

Tags: cordova, push, intel-xdk

For the last couple of days I've been trying to push an update to app preview for an app I'm working on using Intel XDK. It says it has pushed ([pushed less than 1 minute ago](https://i.gyazo.com/aa265bf28b9c42f3185096a11cad708f.png)) but when I open the app on App Preview it has the old app version i.e. before the fixes. This has been a recurring issue for the last 2/3 days (I think when 2548 was released). I'm not sure if this is an issue on their end or my end. This prevents me from building the app as it is using an old version of the app when it makes the APK.

**Note:** If I switch to the WIFI ([WIFI tab](https://i.gyazo.com/8f08dd5e3647645ad3ef15e6b7ad5e7f.png)) test mode on the TEST page and scan the QR code it brings the updated version up in app preview.

So my question is, is there anything I can do to overcome this issue because it's wasting a lot of time as some plugins that I'm using require you to build the APK to test them?

**Other Information**

[image: I've tried 4.1.2 too.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went back to the app, I removed all the plugins and reinstalled them. The issue was that plugin formally known as *Dialog* was renamed to *Notification*. So XDK would try to find a plugin which didn't exist. After removing that plugin and adding the *Notification* plugin everything started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Your built apps do not use the "test push" code.  When you build your app, it pushes the app up to the cloud (different slot in S3) and builds from there.

Are you still experiencing the problem though?